# Signal "0" error while scrolling a tableview with images

Tags: iphone, uitableview, memory-leaks, uiimage, dealloc

I have a problem while scrolling images on tableview.

I am getting a  Signal "0" error.

I think it is due to some memory issues but I am not able to find out the exact error.
The code is as follows,

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";`

```
    UITableViewCell *cell = [travelSummeryPhotosTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {           
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];

    }

    //Photo ImageView
    UIImageView *photoTag = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, 5.0, 85.0, 85.0)];

    NSString *rowPath =[[imagePathsDictionary valueForKey:[summaryTableViewDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    photoTag.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:rowPath];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:photoTag];

    [photoTag release];

    // Image Caption
    UILabel *labelImageCaption = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110.0, 15.0, 190.0, 50.0)];
    labelImageCaption.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    NSString *imageCaptionText =[   [imageCaptionsDictionary valueForKey:[summaryTableViewDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    labelImageCaption.text = imageCaptionText;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:labelImageCaption];
    [labelImageCaption release];

    return cell;

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Signal "0" error* usually means that application crashed because of low memory.

It seems that your problem is the following - you create cell subviews and add them to your cell each time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method gets called - so all your allocated UI elements hang in memory and application gets out of it eventually.

To solve your problem you must create cell's subviews only once - when creating it and later just setup their contents:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [travelSummeryPhotosTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {           
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];

        UIImageView *photoTag = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, 5.0, 85.0, 85.0)];
        photoTag.tag = 10;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:photoTag];
        [photoTag release];

        UILabel *labelImageCaption = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110.0, 15.0, 190.0, 50.0)];
        labelImageCaption.tag = 11;
        labelImageCaption.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:labelImageCaption];
        [labelImageCaption release];
    }

    //Photo ImageView
    NSString *rowPath =[[imagePathsDictionary valueForKey:[summaryTableViewDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImageView* photoTag = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];
    photoTag.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:rowPath];

    // Image Caption
    UILabel *labelImageCaption = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:11];
    NSString *imageCaptionText =[   [imageCaptionsDictionary valueForKey:[summaryTableViewDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    labelImageCaption.text = imageCaptionText;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir for quick reply !!  I have updated the code. The application is not crashing but the scrolling of TableView is very very slow. 

I am loading images from documents directory at the run time. Is it the reason for slow scrolling? What is the standard way of storing images? Should I create a image array and access it? Does size of the images also affects the scrolling speed? Does memory leaks in other classes cause the slow scrolling?

Comment: have a look at Apple's LazyTableImages sample - http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html